# edit request data by converting to array then how to convert array to request object

Tags: laravel

```
$data=$request->all();
```

Here I can convert $request into an array How to reverse this operation
How to convert $data to $request

Comment: I am not exactly sure how easy it is to do so, but why do you need to do that? I have used Laravel for 6+ years and I had never done that. Could you show us the code you are using so that we see why you need to do so? This is a very big code smell